# Can we properly sort all this [cargo]?

Tags: support, tag-disambiguation

The tag [cargo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cargo) is currently defined to be about some Java EE tool, but it's often used to be about the Rust tool [rust-cargo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-cargo) (currently 77 questions [`[rust] [cargo]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cargo+rust)) or a site builder [cargo.site](https://cargo.site) (31 questions found with [`[cargo] site`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcargo%5D+site).

With only about 305 tagged questions this shouldn't be too much work, I suggest retagging all questions about the questions about the site builder as [cargo.site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cargo.site), the ones about the Rust tool to [rust-cargo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-cargo), once the wrongly tagged questions are gone, I'd like to have the tag renamed to [java-cargo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-cargo) to avoid further misuse.

Comment: Are questions about the website (cargo.site) even on topic for [so]?  I opened the link and was bombarded by a bunch of marquees as I'm on mobile (was a truly awful experience)

Comment: Well the questions I looked at involved programming JavaScript or writing HTML so I would think so, at least you can ask on-topic questions about it, if we need that tag is another question at only about 31 questions, but I like to err on the side where we don't remove info that's there already (i.e. I'd like to keep any tag if applicaple)

Comment: If the question is about HTML or JavaScript they should use those tags. What does the website have to do with the question? If you tag [[tag:cargo.site]] then you are staying you are asking about cargo.site, so what about that site specifically is on topic? That the site you're deploying to will be that website is irrelevant, much like [[tag:visual-studio]] and [[tag:iis]] rarely belong on a question about C# and Entity Framework.

Comment: Looking at a few of the questions about cargo.site it appears that the site is irrelevant to the question; they are about a language not the site (that they are using the website isnt related to the question). Questions that *are* about site appear to be completely off topic ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74307078/2029983), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75574901/2029983) as quick examples). *Maybe* questions about the site would be on-topic on [webapps.se], but I don't know anything about the site, so I honestly have no idea.

Comment: The main problem here is that there is a natural influx of questions about Cargo, as in the Rust building system, and many of the folks' natural reaction is to use [tag:cargo] instead of [tag:rust-cargo]. It is curious to find that this proposal is being contested over whether the Cargo referring to the site for Java EE development should have its own tag at all. But hey, if you manage to discover that [tag:cargo] as it exists right now makes no sense, it would be great for it to exist as a synonym of [tag:rust-cargo].

Comment: In the end all I really care for is for those questions not to be tagged \[[tag:cargo]\]. If everyone is on board, I'm very happy to just remove the tag from those.

Comment: @Enet4 I was asking for clarification on the external site being on-topic; considering the suggestion here it's important to know. We shouldn't be creating tags for off-topic questions, we should be removing the tag from on-topic questions and closing (and deleting) those that aren't on-topic.

Comment: As for the Java Vs Rust, they should be disambiguated, and the Cargo tag should (likely) be made a synonym of which ever is "more popular"; that [[tag:cargo]] is ambiguous means that it's not a good tag (any more).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some time has passed and the community did some cleanup, all current questions tagged [cargo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cargo) are about the Java EE tool (+ API) given that there were about [504 mistagged Rust questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1795082/posts-wrongly-tagged-cargo-instead-of-rust-cargo) (that's over twice the number of questions tagged [cargo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cargo)) which stand against only 189 questions currently tagged [cargo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cargo) (presumably correctly) the now ambiguous tag

1. [cargo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cargo) should be renamed to [codehaus-cargo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codehaus-cargo) avoiding conflating the maven plugin with the rest of the api & web interface
2. the now free [cargo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cargo) should be made a synonym of the vastly more popular [rust-cargo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-cargo) (roughly 10× more questions)

Answer (score 2):

From a look at questions about the external site, Cargo.site, the subject doesn't appear to be on-topic for the Stack Overflow.

I would therefore suggest:

1. For questions about the site, the tag should be removed if they are still on-topic. If they aren't on-topic then they should be VTC'd and deleted.
2. Questions with [cargo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cargo) which are about the the Java tool be retagged to [maven-cargo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven-cargo), as that appears to be what they are really about and that tag already exists. If they are tagged with both [cargo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cargo) and [maven-cargo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven-cargo) then the former should be removed.
3. Likewise questions about the Rust Crate should have [rust-cargo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-cargo) added to their tags and/or [cargo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cargo) removed.

To then avoid the problem in the future, the tag [cargo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cargo) should be made a synonym of one of the other tags. Considering that [rust-cargo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-cargo) has a lot more questions than [maven-cargo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven-cargo), then the former would seem the more likely candidate. This would mean step 3 isn't needed.

Comment: I'm not quite sure \[[tag:cargo]\] and \[[tag:maven-cargo]\] are the same, the later looks like it could be a frontend for the former as well since at least from the tagwikis the former isn't exclusively used with maven.

Comment: Given that the [main page for Cargo](https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Home.html) labels itself as "Codehaus Cargo", perhaps that name (`codehaus-cargo`) could be used for what's currently the `cargo`?