# How can we resolve this edit war where the OP continuously rolls back tag edits back to the wrong tag?

Tags: support, edits, edit-wars

There are two questions from the same asker regarding Rust and the Cargo package manager, where they have incorrectly tagged the question [cargo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cargo) when it should be [rust-cargo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-cargo). The former tag is for a Java/Maven tool while the latter is for the Rust package manager.

- [Can I config a build script for specific binary with Cargo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76985234/can-i-config-a-build-script-for-specific-binary-with-cargo) ([edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76985234/revisions))
- [Rust, How to configure a workspace of libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76329073/rust-how-to-configure-a-workspace-of-libraries) ([edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76329073/revisions))

Multiple attempts (mostly by another Rust curator, but some by me) have been made to rectify the error, but the asker keeps rolling back the edits.

Comments have been made regarding this on one of their posts, but thus far the asker has not responded. I have flagged one of the posts for a moderator to hopefully address, but it's been a few days and I haven't gotten a resolution on that either.

I hate to bring meta into what seems like a petty problem. Is there something more I could do?

Comment: Why not simply flag a moderator with a custom flag? Ah, I see that you have done this already. Then sit back and wait for the moderator to take action as there is no need to rush this thing. They are super busy as I understand it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels alright, I kinda figured that was the case. Do you know what has them busy? Just curious. Usually my flags are resolved within a day or so.

Comment: Looks like the posts in question have been locked by a mod.

Comment: A mod should be flagged before "keeps rolling back" happens.

Comment: @philipxy I agree. I personally would have flagged on the second rollback. Alas I did not know this was even happening until much later.

Comment: Seems like part of the problem, however, is the ambiguity of having a tag [[tag:cargo]]; as the tag is meant to be specifically about a Java/Maven tool then perhaps it should be renamed.

Comment: @ThomA well I think you might remember [we tried](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424889/can-we-properly-sort-all-this-cargo), so far, no dice.

Comment: I don't, in truth.It looks like it just needs a rename at this point, @cafce25 , so a lot of progress *was* made.

Comment: @ThomA yeah but who does the rename (and synonym creation). It seems like it is an easy process for tags which just have a few dangling questions and tags that everyone understands so there is no doubt what is right or wrong, but for tags such as "cargo" which are more niche... nobody dares, nobody cares.

Comment: In the past I believe these have handled by mods after the community vote on [[meta-tag:feature-request]] and work has been done to ensure that the rename won't cause other complications (such as tagging questions incorrectly), @Gimby